# Shell_exec function is causing http error 500 in php

Tags: php, bash

I have a php script as shown below:

```
<?php

$output = shell_exec(/var/www/html/scripts/script.sh hello);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

?>
```

and when the output variable uses *exec* or *shell_exec* then I get HTTP error 500 but when I change it for something else such as *getcwd()* it works fine. *Exec* and *shell_exec* are not disabled in *php.ini* and the script has all relevant permissions so I have no idea what is going on.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Strings need to be quoted in PHP. `/var/www/html/scripts/script.sh hello` is a string.

Comment: you have to rtm on `shell_exec()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php - `string shell_exec ( string $cmd )`.

Comment: Also when getting a 500 check your error logs, you will be a much more descriptive error.

Comment: @user3783243 Thanks very much, I no longer get the error and the page loads but it now loads to a blank page. When I did a quick search on it it said things like make sure you have a relative/absolute path - both of which I've tried - 
 and make sure it has permissions. The script is fine as it runs fine from the shell it's just in php where whatever I echo does not get assigned to the output variable. Other linux commands such as _ls -l_ or _pwd_ work fine it's just running the bash script

Comment: Maybe the apache user doesn't have permission to execute that script? Your error logs should give you information about what is happening

Comment: @user3783243 I looked at the error logs and it says permission denied so just to be safe I changed the directory as well as all the scripts to 777 permissions and made every parent directory owned by the apache user but it has no effect and I'm still getting permission denied in the error log

Comment: Change to your apache user and trying running the script, does it work in that instance?

Comment: It turned out to be SELinux blocking apache from doing anything to the folder so I'm just trying to give it permissions now because it works in permissive mode but not enforcing

Comment: No. The code you've shown would not give the behaviour you described in your question nor in this comment.

Comment: @symcbeanIt turns out to be the quotation marks that gave the http 500 error and SELinux blocking access to other directories

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours of research I finally found the answer. I'm using CentOS 7 so there was an instance of SELinux running so I tried to set it to permissive and then it allowed me to save the file to any directory that I gave write permissions to. Following that I used the allowed2audit command to give permissions for httpd to read write and execute files and it now works on enforcing mode.

Thanks to everyone who contributed to help me figure it out :)